# macbook pro: windows are too big on external Samsung 32" monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution

I purchased this Samsung 32" external monitor which is 1920 x 1080p:
https://www.walmart.com/ip/Samsung-32-Curved-1920x1080-HDMI-60hz-4ms-FHD-LCD-Monitor-LC32F39MFUNXZA-Speakers-Included/374473324

When I plugged it into my 2018 Macbook pro with touchbar, the windows appear much bigger in comparison to my other Dell 32" external monitor which has a higher resolution (2560 x 1440).
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07JVQ8M3Q/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JVQ8M3Q)

I want to have more desktop space on the Samsung monitor so I want the windows to be smaller.  At the current resolution, it looks like it's much lower resolution than 1920 x 1080.  is there any way to make the windows smaller?

I tried holding option when pressing "scaled" in display options but it only gave lower resolutions which made the windows even bigger.

And yes, I know how to resize windows.  I am asking how to make the text/windows appear smaller when I drag them onto the external monitor.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is a 'no fix' situation.

Your new monitor just doesn't have the capability to make things any smaller. 1920x1080 is "HD" standard television resolution (sometimes now called "1k"). At 32" it's going to be good for watching TV or working from 2 or 3m away.
32" at 2560 x 1440, called  "1440p" or "2k" resolution would be better but still I'd consider a bit big for a 2k screen you work at on a desk. Personally I consider 27" to be right for 2k.

You can't make the screen display any more pixels than it has.

Comment: Watch for marketing-speak in descriptions: "The Samsung 32" Curved LCD Monitor is all you need for entertainment and gaming." 'Entertainment' here meaning TV/Netflix/Etc. and **not** working on your computer. For that price you won't get a higher resolution monitor, and that is nothing more than a small TV and not a big computer monitor.

Comment: ah i see, ok thanks guys.  I will be returning it then.